# Java: Is it possible to execute the modified code of a method (changed in runtime) using its existing invocations

Tags: java, reflection, runtime, dynamic-class-loaders, runtimemodification

I got many similar questions on SO but still trying to figure out if we can replace a method body at runtime and can that modified method be executed by the existing invocations to that method.

After reading many answers to similar questions, I learned that we can replace any user defined class at runtime. Then we can load the modified class (e.g., there is a modified method in the modified class), create an instance of that class, and invoke the modified method. The accepted answer to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316996/how-to-replace-classes-in-a-running-application-in-java/14317506#14317506) was very helpful for me to understand the concept.

Basically the example used in that answer explains that if we change `Test1.hello()`, that would be picked by the `main` method in `Test` class since it is creating a new instance of `Test1` class and invoking hello through that instance.

```
Class cls = new TestClassLoader().loadClass("test.Test1");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
cls.getMethod("hello").invoke(obj);
```

But there can be situations, where there are many existing calls to `hello()` in the code base (e.g., in `Test2.java`), and we want that after we load the the `Test1` class dynamically, all the existing invocations in `Test2` would execute the modified method, not the old one.

I was wondering if it is possible at all, or if I am missing something.

Thanks much in advance.