# Why does JUnitCore only return the first results?

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-jdt, mutation-testing

I am using JUnit 4 with Eclipse JDT to create automated Mutant testing.

Here is the general overview of my code structure:

```
//Basic for loop
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    //Read in source code from a Java file
    ...(works)

    //Change a line using JDT and save code to a new Java file
    ...(works)

    //Compile new Java file (this also works)
    try {       
        Process compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -cp \"src/*\" " + path + "*.java");
        compile.waitFor();
    } catch(IOException ex) { /*...*/ }
      catch(InterruptedException ex) { /*...*/ }

    //Run JUnit Tests (this works the first time it is called)
    JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = core.run(JUnitTest.class); //This class contains my JUnit Tests
}
```

**My code above works for the first test, but every test after that always returns the same results. Why are new results not generated even though different mutations are made?**

Things I have tried:

1. Testing that different mutations are made at every loop iteration.
2. Testing that the new code is compiled before the test is run.
3. Running the internals of the for loop as a thread, wait for that thread to finish, then run the next test.
4. Using JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitTest.class) in lieu of creating an instance of *core* and calling *core.run(JUnitTest.class)*:

   ```
   JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
   Result result = core.run(JUnitTest.class);
   ```
5. Substituting JUnitCore (org.junit) code for TestRunner (junit.textui), which gave me the same problem:

   ```
   TestSuite suite= new TestSuite();
   suite.addTestSuite(JUnitTest.class);
   TestResult result = TestRunner.run(suite);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the mutant into the JVM - although you are compiling the modified file the JVM will only see the first loaded version.

There are various ways to do this, from launching a new JVM for each mutant through to using the instrumentation API.

Comment: Brilliant. I have considered launching a new JVM for each mutant, but I would like to know how to use instrumention to replace classes in the JVM. Do you have any links of where to start?

Comment: @ZacharyTerlizzese Start with the official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html then take a look at how pitest does it https://github.com/hcoles/pitest

Comment: Thank you for your help Henry. I have also found this solution that may be able to sub out one class for another using SomeJavaClass.class.getClassLoader():
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14317506/1008395

Comment: Yes you can use either a non-delegating classloader or a delegating one under root. I discuss some of the pros and cons of this (and other implementation considerations for mutating java) here -> http://pitest.org/java_mutation_testing_systems/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running the loop from *i=0* to *i=10*,
and if using this loop than where are you using the value of *i* inside the code. I think this not using the value of *i* resulting you the same result every time.

Comment: The loop is a summary of more advanced code. In reality I am searching the code for every Infix Expression and mutating it. The number of loops may vary so for simplicity I have advertised the question as simply running 10 times (though even twice does not work).